# How to sustain iodine vapor in a big container (V=200 L)?

Tags: vapor-pressure, containers

I am lost in a quest on how to have a big container in which I can have iodine vapor at a known temperature.

We intend send iodine into an air flow, and observe fluorescence of iodine in this flow. This method is known as planar laser induced fluorescence. The challenge lies in the fact that, we need to be able to send iodine above a certain concentration for about several minutes. The idea is to have a large volume of iodine vapor ready, so that we do not run out of iodine vapor during the experiment and we do not need to wait too long between experiment sessions for iodine to sublimate.

In order to do that, I came up with the idea that we will have a big volume of container, and we will heat this container. The bigger the container, the more iodine vapor mass will be ready for us to send to the experimental chamber. Otherwise, if we had a smaller volume, iodine would deplete quicker and I would have to wait for sublimation.

So, with this purpose, I want to do be able to get a container, and I am trying to come up with a way to heat it up. What kind of a barrel, or container of some other type would be suitable for me, and how could I heat it so that it is around 80-100 C?

Comment: Your message is not clear. You speak of an air flow. Well ! Do you need a heated container with motionless air + iodine or will you produce an air jet ? On the other hand, iodine reacts with most metals, producing iodides. Have you taken this into account ?

Comment: Well, the idea is to first heat container long enough so that there's saturated iodine in the container. Then I will generate flow into and out from the container, there will be an air jet.

And about the reaction with metals, yes I thought about it, that's why I was thinking of a plastic barrel. 

Have I made it clear or is something still missing?

Comment: You should describe the expt. in more detail. What sort of air pressure, what sort of I2 concentration, flow rate, expanding into vacuum or not etc. It would be better to do this dynamically, pass gas (air or O2 or N2?) over reservoir of solid iodine at  temp to get vpr pressure you need.

Comment: Why don't you pre-heat the air rather?

Comment: Usual plastics are good solvent to iodine $\ce{I2}$. So I would not recommend using  a plastic container for iodine vapor. The best container would be in glass, as metals are oxidized by iodine vapor, and plastics absorb iodine.